# Are these two expression square integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have two expressions (let's call them functions $f,g$) on $[0,1]$, where I want to find out whether they are square-integrable or better: for which $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ they are square-integrable ( the problem of course is that it is impossible to evaluate the integrals explicitely):

$$f(x) = (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}^m}{\sqrt{1-x}^m} e^{ \beta x} \int_0^x \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}^{2m}}{(1-t^2)e^{2 \beta t}} dt$$

and

$$g(x) = (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}-m} e^{ \beta x} \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{1-t^2}^{1-2m}e^{2 \beta t}} dt.$$

The only thing I know for sure is that the prefactors are at least square integrable for $m \le 0$.

Comment: You may want to show a bit better than $L^2$ in the prefactor. To show $f$ is $L^2$ it is enough to show the prefactor is $L^{2p}$ and the integral term is $L^{2(p/(p-1))}$ for some $p \geq 1$ (where we have the convention $1/0 = \infty$). This follows from Holder's inequality. Also you should specify the desired domain; from context I assume it is $[0,1]$.

Comment: I added the domain. But Holder's inequality is an inequality, so it's just useful if I have a positive answer for this particular $m$.

Comment: Holder's inequality can tell you that the integral is finite. It may lead you astray and think that it is infinite when it is actually finite, but that's about it. Also, your $e^{\beta t}$ is in a scope where $t$ is not defined (inside the integral it's fine, but outside not so much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at $f$. In what follows, $C_i$ are functions which are bounded away from both $0$ and $\infty$. The prefactor may be written as

$$C_1(x) (1-x)^{-m/2+1/4}$$

The integrand may be written as

$$C_2(t) (1-t)^{m-1}$$

Thus for $m \neq 0$, the integral may be written as

$$C_3(x) (1-x)^m$$

while for $m=0$ we have

$$C_4(x) \ln(1-x)$$

Thus overall for $m \neq 0$ we have

$$f(x) = C_5(x) (1-x)^{m/2+1/4}$$

and for $m = 0$ we have

$$f(x) = C_6(x) (1-x)^{1/4} \ln(1-x)$$

The latter is bounded, so it is square integrable. The former, when squared, looks like

$$f^2(x) = C_7(x) (1-x)^{m+1/2}$$

which is integrable provided $m+1/2>-1$. So $f$ is square integrable provided $m \geq -1$ and is *not* square integrable if $m < -1$.

$g$ can be handled in essentially the same fashion as $f$.